# Android App shuts down while using the Native Camera App

Tags: java, android, camera, crash, native

I'm currently developing and maintaining an Android Legacy app, native in Java. The App has been growing slowly throughout the years and I think the original architecture design it falling a bit short.

The app opens the native android camera, and for some reason, it kills the process in background, perhaps due to lack of resources. I've tested different flows with the android profiler, and wasted a lot of time trying to pinpoint what its happening. The flow goes as this:

The app is filled with data, using a SQL DB and static variables, then at some point the user is required to use the native camera to retrive a photo, then return to the app and keep on with the process. Sometimes, the process dies while being in the native camera app, and when returning, all the data stored on the static variables are empty, thus crashing the app and restarting itself.

Using the Android Studio Profiler, I found that when the process dies, it prints this in the console:

```
2021-11-18 22:19:54.906 9177-9762/es.myapp I/PhenotypeProcessReaper: Memory state is: 400
2021-11-18 22:19:54.906 9177-9762/es.myapp I/PhenotypeProcessReaper: Killing process to refresh experiment configuration
2021-11-18 22:19:54.906 9177-9762/es.myapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9177 SIG: 9
```

Does anyone has any idea of what is happening? What is PhenotypeProcessReaper?

I'm trying to write a class to save the states of all the data to be able to recover the app after the process, but in the mean time I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: It also happens to me when my app tries to get a location update with LocationManager.requestLocationUpdate on background mode. Motorola g42 on Android 12. The same stack trace with memory state is 400